# How to transfer data from a DB into another DB both in the same Redshift cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a Redshift cluster with 2 DBs in it, let's say `A` and `B`. Now `A` has a table `my_schema.my_table` and I'd like to transfer periodically data from this table to one in `B` having the same schema and same table names.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

This functionality was announce last Oct and is currently in preview.

See: [Announcing cross-database queries for Amazon Redshift (preview)](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/10/announcing-cross-database-queries-for-amazon-redshift-preview/)

If you cannot wait and cannot get on the preview, the best path is unloading out to S3 and then copying back into the other database (or reference with Redshift spectrum if you prefer).

Answer (score 0):

An idea might be to UNLOAD from `A`

```
unload ('select * from my_schema.my_table') 
to 's3://my-bucket/product' 
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=<your key here>;aws_secret_access_key=<your key here>
' MANIFEST  DELIMITER '|' NULL AS 'null_string' ESCAPE ALLOWOVERWRITE;
```

and COPY in `B`

```
copy my_schema.my_table 
from 's3://my-bucket/productmanifest' 
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=<your key here>;aws_secret_access_key=<your key here>'
MANIFEST DELIMITER '|' NULL AS 'null_string' ESCAPE;
```

based on https://optimalbi.com/moving-redshift-data-between-databases/ but I'm looking for smarter solutions if possible (without adding the cost of transferring data across S3) so other answers are more than welcome.

Answer (score 0):

How about a simple `insert into` with a `select`

```sql
create table category_ident
(catid int identity not null,
catgroup varchar(10) default 'General',
catname varchar(10) default 'General',
catdesc varchar(50) default 'General');


insert into category_ident(catgroup,catname,catdesc)
select catgroup,catname,catdesc from category;
```

This is taken from the [Redshift INSERT examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Examples_of_INSERT_30.html)

Should work as well if you prefix the table names with the database/schema names as long as it's in the same cluster.

Comment: not sure is possible, I tested and get `[0A000][500310] [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: cross-database reference to database "A" is not supported;`, am I missing anything?

Comment: Looks like my brain had saved  the announcement [Bill Weiner referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66325012/6485881) as generally available already - my bad.